How to adjust LazyHGrid to the bottom of the screen?
I'm just learning SwiftUI and currently working on my first project.
I'm trying to get rid of this space between my LazyHGrid block and the screen bottom:

var body: some View { 
    VStack {
        cards(theme: theme)
        //Spacer()
        LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100))]) {
            cardCountAdjuster(by: -1, symbol: "rectangle.stack.badge.minus.fill", theme: theme)
            themeAdjusters.frame(alignment: .center)
            cardCountAdjuster(by: +1, symbol: "rectangle.stack.badge.plus.fill", theme: theme)
        }.padding()
    }
}

func themeAdjuster(theme_num: Int) -> some View{
    Button{
        if cardCount > emojis[theme_num].count - 1 {cardCount = emojis[theme_num].count}
        emojis[theme_num].shuffle()
        theme = theme_num
    } label: {
        VStack{
            Image(systemName: img_them[theme_num])
            Text(themes[theme_num]).font(.caption)
        }
    }
}

func cardCountAdjuster(by offset: Int, symbol: String, theme: Int) -> some View {
    Button {
        cardCount += offset
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: symbol)
    }
    .disabled(cardCount + offset < 0 || cardCount + offset > emojis[theme].count)          
    .foregroundColor(.purple)
}

I've tried different methods, viewed different tutorials, but still can't get rid of this space between bottom of the screen and my buttons block.
On Iphone 15 Pro screen there is no space, the space is only showing on Iphone SE 3rd gen.
P.S. nothing happens when I do this:
LazyHGrid {}.frame(alignment: .bottom)


It does not work as you like with the Spacer in-between?

Yes, I tried to apply different methods, but non of them works.
I feel like I'm missing something important and that's why I'm having this issue.
The reason why I decided to use LazyHGrid instead of HStack, is because I wanted to make a size of this buttons adaptive to the screen size.

Did you tried to set frame max width and length to infinity on the VStack (alongside with the Soacer you commented) ?

As suggested by @Ptit Xav:
You need a Spacer between your main content and the button row that will push the two views apart. And to use all the available screen space, use a frame modifier with infinite width, like in this exemplary solution:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("CardsView")
            Spacer()
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100))]) {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Label("Adjust -1", systemImage:  "rectangle.stack.badge.minus.fill")
                        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                }
                Text("Theme buttons ...")
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Label("Adjust +1", systemImage:  "rectangle.stack.badge.plus.fill")
                        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

Note that I use LazyVGrid instead of LazyHGrid, which seems to be the right choice.
